# Unity3D - Problema com a authenticação do plugin BitRave para conexão com o Azure

Tags: unity3d, microsoft-azure

Estou seguindo o tutorial:

http://www.deadlyfingers.net/azure/unity3d-game-dev-with-azure-mobile-services-using-bitrave-plugin/

e no momento de fazer o login no Unity Editor aparece a mensagem: "Response is: Unauthorized"

Já refiz várias vezes o tutorial e mesmo assim não consigo encontrar o problema. Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o tutorial:

> 7. Open AzureUI.cs script and replace the connection strings with your own Mobile Service URL & API Key.

Traduzindo:

> 7. Abra o script AzureUI.cs e substitua as strings de conexão com a **sua** Mobile Service URL & chave de API.

Negritei o **sua** porque é aí que está o problema.
Aparentemente a sua chave de API não é válida. Você deve obter uma chave válida única para você para que isso funcione. Esta chave é particular e pessoal de sua propriedade, e não deve ser compartilhada com outras pessoas (é algo como um login e senha). Por isso, não dá para utilizar a chave que está no tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui encontrar o problema:

Fui no portal do Azure, em serviços móveis - identidade - configuraçoes do facebook e preenchi os campos de ID e Senha com os dados que estão no app do facebook, dai começou a funcionar!

Valew